# Linux make 1 big from 3 smaller pictures

Tags: linux

I need to automate a task where I have smaller jpg/png images what I would like to merge into 1 big picture by placing them in a square area.

Obviously to do this I would need to open gimp every time. Create a new big image, like
1920x1200 and open the 4 smaller images, select them and copy paste them into the new one and save it.

The solution I looking for don't have to be the pretties, it's enough if it "just works" tm.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use ImageMagick for this.

see this: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#concatenate

```
  montage image1.png image2.png image3.png image4.png \
      -mode Concatenate  -tile 2x2  output.png
```